# PAGINATION using class APIView in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, pagination

I have try to paginate my data.. but this is not work , I'm still getting all data from DataBase
this is views.py :

```
class User_apiView(APIView):
    pagination_class=PageNumberPagination
    def get(self, request):
        user = User.objects.all() 
        # pagination_class=PageNumberPagination
        serializer = TripSerializer(user, many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

this is settings.py :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 2,
}
```

this the data I recieve in this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/?PAGE=4&PAGE_SIZE=1

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 115,
        "is_normaluser": null,
        "is_agency": null,
        "last_login": "2022-02-11T20:28:13.506519Z",
        "is_superuser": true,
        "first_name": "qaz",
    },
    {
        "id": 115,
        "is_normaluser": null,
        "is_agency": null,
        "last_login": "2022-02-11T20:28:13.506519Z",
        "is_superuser": true,
        "first_name": "qaz",
    },
    {
        "id": 115,
        "is_normaluser": null,
        "is_agency": null,
        "last_login": "2022-02-11T20:28:13.506519Z",
        "is_superuser": true,
        "first_name": "qaz",
    },
   
]
```

Comment: Because you override the `get` method, you omit the pagination part...

Comment: From the [pagination docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagination) - `Pagination is only performed automatically if you're using the generic views or viewsets. If you're using a regular APIView, you'll need to call into the pagination API yourself to ensure you return a paginated response. See the source code for the mixins.ListModelMixin and generics.GenericAPIView classes for an example`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination, etc. only works for `APIView`s that have implemented the logic for pagination, for example a `ListAPIView`. You this can work with:

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class User_apiView(ListAPIView):
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TripSerializer
```

This will implement the `.get(…)` method that will fetch the paginated queryset, and use the serializer to serialize the data and put it into a response.